# Adding an array's content to an unordered list as list elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, list

So i got this list

```
<ul>
  <li> This is</li>
  <li> a very nice</li>
  <li> list</li>
</ul>
```

- This is
- a very nice
- list

and this code to put the content of the array into the list

```
var nevek =["tom", "bob","kate"];
nevek.forEach(element => {
    $('ul').append( " <li> element  </li>");
```

But instead of adding the content from the array, it just adds  3 new listitems like this

- This is
- a very nice
- list
- element
- element
- element

How should I refer to the individual element in the array to print them out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should append the element at each iteration instead of the string, this can be done using [`template literals`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) as follows:

```js
var nevek =["tom", "bob","kate"];
nevek.forEach(element => {
    $('ul').append( ` <li> ${element}  </li>`);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
     <li> This is</li>
     <li> a very nice</li>
     <li> list</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. Could you tell me why you need to use ` here instead "?    (compared to Java, JS has too many " ` ˝ [ and { for my taste :D )

Comment: You are welcome, this is a nice feature in JS where you can include a variable dynamically in a string instead of doing: " <li>"+element+"</li>"  like in your case